# Filter:blur.svg in Opera and IE (Window/Linux) not working

Tags: css, svg

I followed many tutorials and stackoverflow questions that basically say all teh same thing, but for me is still not working (don't show any blur effect or any effect in IE and FF/Opera for Windows and Linux)

This my css:

```
-webkit-filter: blur(20px);
-moz-filter: blur(15px);
-o-filter: blur(15px);
-ms-filter: blur(15px);
filter: url(#effect-blur-1);
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'effect-blur-1\'><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation=\'15\' /></filter></svg>#effect-blur-1");
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='3');
```

I already try to put the svg in a external file. No positive outcome as well.
Even to use this:

```
filter:blur(add = 0, direction = 300, strength = 10);
```

but still nothing.

Anyone know where i'm wrong?

Comment: Yep, here there is: http://jsfiddle.net/vVLuY/

Comment: Yes sorry my bad. In Firefox it works but not in IE and Opera for Windows/Linux. Actually Firefox in Window just show blue color. I'm try to understand more about it..

Comment: You can't apply SVG filters to HTML content with IE. You'd have to make the image an SVG `<image>` element.

Comment: ok I updated: http://jsfiddle.net/vVLuY/4/ You mean something like that? And that will work even for Chrome and other browsers where was already working?

Comment: Not really. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE10/11 don't support applying filters to html content, only SVG content so your image must be an SVG `<image>` element and not an html `<img>` element.

In addition IE doesn't seem to support data URL filters, at least I couldn't make it work so we're left with this which seems to work on IE11 and Firefox and probably webkit too...

```
<header>
      <div>
        <div>
            <svg width="650" height="400">
            <image width="650" height="400" xlink:href="http://www.insidefacebook.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/iOS7update.jpg" filter="url(#blur)" />
    <filter id="blur">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3" />
    </filter>
            </svg>
        </div>
      </div>
</header>
```

or as a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/f893r/)

Comment: still cannot make it work :( can you make it a fiddle please?

Comment: Sure but I'm only going to paste in the answer which I did test in Firefox and IE11 already.

Comment: Coool!! Now i get it! I was putting different solution evenin the css that's why it didn't work for me.

Comment: But, is there a way to do it without a specific size? I try to put width and height in css but it seems to not care about not-inline css..

Comment: No with SVG 1.1 width/height are mandatory attributes which cannot be set with CSS. The upcoming and as yet unfinished SVG 2 specification aims to address this shortcoming but I don't think any UA has implemented that yet.